# My AngularJS view is able to access it's controller's scope, but ng-repeat doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, angularjs-ng-repeat, meanjs

I'm building a MEAN app and used yeoman to scaffold the client side code.  I have a controller and view called movies.

Here is the movie controller:

```
'use strict';

/**                                                                                                                                                                                  
 * @ngdoc function                                                                                                                                                                   
 * @name clientApp.controller:MoviesCtrl                                                                                                                                             
 * @description                                                                                                                                                                      
 * # MoviesCtrl                                                                                                                                                                      
 * Controller of the clientApp                                                                                                                                                       
 */
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function () {
      this.movies = [
          {
              title: 'A New Hope',
              url: 'http://youtube.com/embed/1g3_CFmnU7k'
          },
          {
              title: 'The Empire Strikes Back',
              url: 'http://youtube.com/embed/96v4XraJEPI'
          },
          {
              title: 'Return of the Jedi',
              url: 'http://youtube.com/embed/5UfA_aKBGMc'
          }
      ];

  });
```

Here is the movie view:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>URL</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
      <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
      <td>{{movie.url}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
{{movies}}
```

When I view the page in my browser, the ng-repeat doesn't work (nothing is printed out), but where I explicitly print out {{movies}} in the view, I see the movies json that I defined in the controller.  So, I know that the view has access to the controller's scope.

Why isn't ng-repeat working even when the view has access to the controller's scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use this.movies, you need to use controller AS syntax (MovieCtrl as ctrl). Even so, you may run into problems if you don't save controller object (e.g., vm = this)

The way you have it now, you need to assign to $scope instead of this

Comment: Assigning movies to $scope.movies instead of this.movies in the controller fixed the problem.  I also had to include ng-controller="MoviesCtrl" in the view.

Comment: Of course! I assumed that `ng-controller="MoviesCtrl"` is on a higher level (in the body or div tag). Glad I could help. Do you mind to mark the answer as "accepted"?

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat creates a new child scope, but your parent scope doesn't have the movies object, so you would have to inject $scope into the controller and specify it how it's normally done (e.g. $scope.movies = ... ) .

For this case when you want to use the "this" keyword, you just need to use "MoviesCtrl as moviesCtrl" in your markup and then use "moviesCtrl.movies" to get the object in your ng-repeat.

The reason of why {{movie}} seems to work is most likely because of the way interpolation works.